# Hiberante @JoinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I have 2 entity, in first I store the products, second is used to store image of this products as a file path. In example below I removed all field except this relationship.

First class:

```
public class Products {

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "image_file_path")
private List<ProductsImages> productsImagesList;
```

}

Second class:

```
public class ProductsImages {

private String filePath;
```

}

So I wanted to add column image_file_path in table Products to point to Id in ProductsImages, but except that I got image_file_path column in table ProductsImages. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you get the column in the ProductsImages is because you have defined your relationship as **One To Many** . If you have many product images corresponding to single product how can you have a single column in products pointing to image.

You need to figure out if you have one image or many images. If you have one then you can have your column inside Products and that is not a problem , but then you need to modify your relationship to OneToOne.

If you would like to model a relationship where you have one default image, but many other possible images. Then you would need to map it two times one time as OneToMany and one time as OneToOne, this way you would get one column inside the Product where your default image will stand.

Comment: Yes that's indeed problem with structure of my database because I want to have a lot of images related to a single Product.